# How to specify schema for nested json in flask_restx?

Tags: python, flask, swagger, schema, flask-restx

Im using flask_restx for swagger API's. The versions are as follows:

```
python - 3.8.0
flask  - 2.0.2
flask_restx - 0.5.1
```

The following is the nested json I need to specify the schema for:

```
dr_status_fields = app_api.model('DR Status',{
    fields.String: {
        "elasticsearch": {
            "backup_status": fields.String,
            "backup_folder": fields.String,
        },
        "mongodb": {
            "backup_status": fields.String,
            "backup_folder": fields.String,
        },
        "postgresdb": {
            "backup_status": fields.String,
            "backup_folder": fields.String,
        },
        "overall_backup_status": fields.String
    }
})
```

But with this when I load the swagger URL in browser , i get error in the command line:

```
Unable to render schema
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flask_restx/api.py", line 571, in __schema__
    self._schema = Swagger(self).as_dict()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flask_restx/swagger.py", line 268, in as_dict
    "definitions": self.serialize_definitions() or None,
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flask_restx/swagger.py", line 623, in serialize_definitions
    return dict(
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flask_restx/swagger.py", line 624, in <genexpr>
    (name, model.__schema__)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flask_restx/model.py", line 76, in __schema__
    schema = self._schema
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flask_restx/model.py", line 159, in _schema
    properties[name] = field.__schema__
AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute '__schema__'
```

I have tried checking the documentaion of [flask_restx](https://flask-restplus.readthedocs.io/en/stable/swagger.html) for any sample example usage. But could not find any. Please help regarding the same

#### Update

As per `r-m-n` answer i have tried to apply the same. But here the problem is there is a key i.e in Line No.2 of the above defined scheme -> `fields.String: {` . I think this is causing the issue.
I have tried to use it as follows:

```
dr_status_fields = app_api.model('Backup and restore related fields', {
            "backup_status": fields.String,
            "backup_folder": fields.String,
})

dr_db_fields = app_api.model('DR Status', {
    "elasticsearch": fields.Nested(dr_status_fields),
    "mongodb": fields.Nested(dr_status_fields),
    "postgresdb": fields.Nested(dr_status_fields),
    "overall_backup_status": fields.String
})

dr_timestamp_field = app_api.model('Timestamp', {
    fields.String: fields.Nested(dr_db_fields)
})
```

Here the `dr_timestamp_field` has resulted in the same issue.

Comment: you can't use fields as keys, maybe you need a Wildcard Field: https://flask-restplus.readthedocs.io/en/stable/marshalling.html?highlight=Wildcard#wildcard-field

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use [fields.Nested](https://flask-restplus.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#flask_restplus.fields.Nested):

```
backup_fields = api.model('Backup fields', {
    "backup_status": fields.String,
    "backup_folder": fields.String
})

dr_status_fields = api.model('DR Status', {
    "elasticsearch": fields.Nested(backup_fields),
    "mongodb": fields.Nested(backup_fields),
    "postgresdb": fields.Nested(backup_fields),
    "overall_backup_status": fields.String
})
```

Comment: Thanks this has helped me a lot. But there is a issue with one field, can you please check the `Update` section.

Answer (score 0):

There are situations where your value is a list of strings:

> `"titles": fields.List(fields.String, description="Study books"),`

but if you have a dict as a value, then use `fields.Nested` as a parameter:

> `"users": fields.List(fields.Nested(your_model), description="Authors"),`

Also, `your_model` can also nest values as above.